# loop over parents in multi-level tree structure

Tags: ruby, loops, tree

I have a multi-level tree structure and i'm trying to return an array of ancestors for an object which can have 1-3 ancestors. I have a working method, however it's complex and I would prefer to use a loop, anyone know how I can using ruby?

```
def ancestors
  @a = []
  @a.push(parent) if parent.present?
  @a.push(@a.last.parent) if @a.last.parent.present?
  @a.push(@a.last.parent) if @a.last.parent.present?
  return @a
end
```

Comment: Think a recursive solution might be the cleanest

Comment: Can you please prove an example of how I may do this? @KarthikT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand your classes right.. I was thinking something like this

```
def ancestors
   (parent.present? ? [parent, parent.ancestors] :[]).flatten
end
```

If Parent is present, it returns an array consisting of parent and its ancestors. The flatten is required because each level adds a array layer.

Off topic. `return` is considered bad style in ruby, and unless you need it, there is no need for this list to be a member variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for recursion.
You need to make a function which calls itself.
Something like this....

```
def ancestors 
  if self.parent.present?
    ancestors << self.parent.ancestors
  else
    return self
  end
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, I keep getting a 'SystemStackError: stack level too deep'. I can't get it to work properly do you know where I might be going wrong?

Comment: check your exit conditions.  You must alway find a way to unwind the stack.  The exit condition is the most important part of any recursive solution.

Comment: The error is because `ancestors` calls `ancestors`, on itself

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly simple to do this with an iteration as well, you could try

```
def ancestors
  @a = []
  anc=parent
  while anc.present? do
    @a.push anc
    anc=anc.parent
  end
  return @a
end
```

(not tried as I do not have your data structure)